# multiplefile uploader select and show multiple files at once

Tags: yii, multifile-uploader

i want a multiple file uploader (not ajax) for my form.. The features i needed are:
1) ability to select multiple files at once
2) after selection it should display all the filenames (or image) with a button to remove any pic
3) should be able to set number of files limit, file type and file size limit
4) when i submit the form, i should get an array of these files which i can save one by one to a folder and corresponding file names to a database table.

fortunately yii has got the widget '[CMultiFileUpload](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMultiFileUpload)' which serves almost all my purposes except that when i select multiple files and click open it only shows the first file name with a remove button.. i want it to show all the selected files at once.. 
Eg: i select 3 files (i can select multiple files by giving 'multiple'=>'multiple' attribute) and click open then it should show

- [removebutton]file1
- [removebutton]file2
- [removebutton]file3

ll the ajax uploaders have all these functionalities but i cant/don't want to use an ajax uploader because, suppose someone uploads many files using ajax uploader and he then decides to cancel the actual form submission, all the files he uploaded will be there in my uploaded folder, which leads to wastage of space and i have only a limited amount of space in my server. is there any way that i can do this using 'CMultiFileUpload' or is there any other way by which i can do all this? Please help

Comment: if you want to submit form without ajax, then you can use normal html file upload. There is no need of `CMultiFileUpload`.

Answer (score 0):

hope this help your answer,the multi upload in yii http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/176/uploading-multiple-images-with-cmultifileupload/